# Spring Boot Multimodule Inject Error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, module

I've found numerous questions on this problem but none of the solutions worked for me. This project worked without any problems when it was a single module application. When I split the files into different modules I could no longer run it.

The module structure:

```
root
|
|_api
|   \_com.example.utils.mappers.MyObjectMapper.java
|
|
|_persistence
|
|_rest
|   \_com.example.Application.java
|
\_service
    \_com.example.service.MyObjectServiceImpl.java
```

The error:

```
Field myObjectMapper in com.example.service.MyObjectServiceImpl required a bean 
of type 'com.example.utils.mappers.MyObjectMapper' that could not be found.
```

The two files in question, MyObjectMapper:

```
package com.example.utils.mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface myObjectMapper {
  // some mapping functionality
}
```

And the Service class:

```
package com.example.service;

@Service
public class MyObjectServiceImpl implements MyObjectService {

   @Inject
   private MyObjectMapper myObjectMapper;

   /* some DAO calls */
}
```

The class that runs it all:

```
package com.example;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example"}
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  /* call to SpringApplication run method */
}
```

Example of root/pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>root</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>persistence</module>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>rest</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Example of service/pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error had nothing to do with multimodule nature of the project after all. When I was partitioning dependencies from the original pom.xml into the module poms I have only transferred the mapstruct artifact and accidentally left out the second mapstruct-processor artifact.